# Sound Horizon in cosmology

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

I was trying to write the sound horizon in terms of the scale factor, however I don't understand all the steps in the derivation.

I know that I should get:

$$r_{s}=\int_{0}^{a_{d}}\frac{da}{a^{2}H(a)}$$

**What I tried**

$$c_{s}dt=a(t) dr$$

Where $a(t)$ is the scale factor as the function of time, and $c_{s}$ is the velocity of the sound wave

Integrating the last equation:

$$r_{s}=\int _{0}^{t_{d}}\frac{dt}{a(t)}  $$

If I use the relation $H=\frac{\dot{a}}{a}$, then:

$$\mathrm{d} t= \frac{\mathrm{d} a}{Ha}$$
So

$$r_{s}=\int_{0}^{a_{d}}\frac{da}{a^{2}H(a)}  $$

**Question**

I don't understand what is the meaning of the equation $c_{s}dt=a(t)dr$, I just write that equation because I found it in a book.

So where does the equation $c_{s}dt=a(t)dr$ come from ?

**EDIT**

If you have another derivation it will be really helpul if you explain it or provide a link to read about that, I search but I can't find anything clear, most of the books just put the formula and don't explain where it comes from.

Comment: Now just change variables to $a$ instead of $z$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation for the sound horizon is simply the equation for the particle horizon, with the speed of light replaced by the speed of sound, there's nothing more to it. Nevertheless, you have to keep in mind that the speed of sound also changes with time, since the matter density dilutes with a growing scale factor, so you have to treat the speed of sound as a function of the scale factor and integrate over it as well.

Comment: When we talk about the sound horizon in cosmology we are talking about a "Cómovig distance"  or "Physical distance" ? (Please don't take $a_{0}=1$)

Comment: The equation you cited is for the comoving distance, to get the proper distance you have to multiply with $a_0$, see http://lcdm.yukterez.net